# Firefox doesn't recognise the text that it entered in textbox

Tags: javascript, c#, selenium, firefox, selenium-webdriver

I came across a situation where Firefox enters the text in the textbox(within a popup) which is a mandatory field. When I click on the button, it shows the warning flag. When I checked the HTML, it shows that there is no value in the text box and `title` in HTML shows field is required.

I tried using JavaScript to enter the text but it didn't help.

Code Snippet:

```
public static void UserName(string text)
{
    try
    {
        IJavaScriptExecutor js = (IJavaScriptExecutor)Drivers._driverInstance;
        IWebElement element = Drivers._driverInstance.FindElement(By.Id("newName"));
        //js.ExecuteScript("document.getElementById('newName').setAttribute('value', '" + text + "')");
        js.ExecuteScript("arguments[0].click();", element);
        js.ExecuteScript("document.getElementById('newName').value='" + text + "';");
        //Drivers._driverInstance.FindElement(By.Name("newName")).Clear();
       //Drivers._driverInstance.FindElement(By.Name("newName")).SendKeys(text);
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            throw new Exception("Couldn't send text to username textbox " + e);
        }
    }
```

HTML for textbox:

```
<div class="field-container">
<label>Username</label>
<input id="newName" class="input-validation-error" name="newName" data-bind="value: Name" title="This field is required." data-orig-title="This field is required." type="text"/>
<span class="validationMessage" style="">This field is required.</span>
```

[image: Image for reference]

Can someone help me with it.

Version:
Firefox-50.0
Selenium-3.0.0

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

try as follows:

```
driver.findElement(By.Id("newName")).sendKeys(text);
```

Comment: Incorrect `C#` syntax here... should be `FindElement` and `By.Id`

Comment: @PseudoSudo, thanks for notifying. got habituated with Java syntax.

Comment: That didn't work. It entered the text in the textbox but when I click on the button, it shows mandatory warning message. If you refer to the picture, you can see the HTML. An in the code I posted, I already used sendkeys. I tried it with 'Name' and 'Id' too. The problem here is though the text is entered using sendKeys, it doesn't store the value and thinks it's empty.

Comment: try with "driver.findElement(By.Id("newName")).GetAttribute("innerHTML");" and check what is getting printed.

Comment: It's works manually and with Chrome Opera IE and older version of FF too. It's just with the new version I'm facing the issue. Even when I debu, if I manually click and add a character or remove a character from the textbox, it recognises the whole text. Something weird is happening which I couldn't guess. @Naveen will try and get back to you.

Comment: Try with latest geckodriver version. As still the development of geckodriver is in progress and Firefox is getting updated, it could be a compatible issue. So, try the latest geckodriver

Comment: @Naveen I have the latest version of [Gecko](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases). After I entered the text and then tried to retrieve it using GetAttribute(), it prints nothing, it's just blank.

Comment: ok. As it is value data-bind method, switch the focus from the input field (click someplace or switch to another tab), so that value gets updated into the input field, and try ti find the element and retrieve the text.

Comment: @Naveen Sorry for not replying. Yes it displayed the value only when I used GetAttribute("value"). It didn't work for '.Text'

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var username = "User Name Here";
driver.FindElement(By.Id("newName")).sendKeys(username);
```

Comment: It didn't work. Please refer to my comment. Selenium enters the text but when I click the button, it needs to navigate to another page, instead it shows mandatory field error flag.

Answer (score 0):

I would switch to ChromeDriver for now. I do not think webdriver 3.0 is working well with Firefox v50. If you must use firefox, drop down a version and go to a previous version of webdriver.

Comment: There are only 2 test cases which I'm having trouble with(have some other issue which can be solved using some work around). I'm already running in IE and Chrome. Opera stopped working with the latest version.So I had to stop running in Opera. I can't stop with FF too. Can you please tell which version of FF is compatible with latest selenium